# The screen stays off and the laptop is unresponsive after waking from sleep

Tags: keyboard, 16.04, suspend, screen, compaq

I installed ubuntu **16.04 LTS** a week after official release using the **mini ISO**, then **ubuntu-desktop without recommended** packages. Since then, just installing packages on a need to basis.

After trying to wake the computer from sleep by using the touchpad, the light on the power button stops blinking and I hear the sound of the hard drive coming online. But :

- the screen stays completely off, no backlight.
- the laptop doesn't respond to any keyboard presses.
- Everytime I use The magic SysRq to restart the laptop. Long pressing the power button works too.

This problem wasn't present when using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

The proposed solutions in all the possible duplicates on this website didn't solve my problem. One big difference is that my **laptop screen is off** not just blank.

Possible helpful informations. All got after system reboot.

- [dmesg](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16342192/)
- [var/log/syslog](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16342269/)

**HARDWARE DETAILS :**

**Computer Model :**

Hewlett-Packard Compaq Presario C700 Notebook PC/30D9, BIOS F.35 03/29/2010

> **uname -a**

```
Linux CPC700 4.4.0-22-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 5 16:53:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

> **lspci -nn :**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub [8086:2a00] (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) [8086:2a02] (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) [8086:2a03] (rev 03)
```

> **sudo lshw -class display**

```
*-display:0
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:26 memory:91000000-910fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:30d0(size=8)
*-display:1 UNCLAIMED
   description: Display controller
   product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2.1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
   version: 03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:91100000-911fffff
```

**EDIT 1**
I think this is a bug, because it doesn't happen all the time anymore. I would file it as such on launchpad but I don't know which packages cause the problem. How can I go on to find them in my specific case ?

**EDIT 2**
With the setting "**When the lid is closed : do nothing**".

- The system doesn't go to sleep when I close the lid.
- Content of listens (**acpi_listen > ~/listens**) :

  > button/lid LID close
  >   button/lid LID open

Comment: What happens if in terminal you type in `sudo pm-suspend` ?  If it says unknown command, install with `sudo apt-get install pm-utils` and try again.

Comment: @XToro it goes to sleep and I can wake it up normally.

Comment: Your monitor maybe off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/779220/xubuntu-16-04-second-monitor-disabled-after-display-sleep

Answer (score 1):

After confirming in the comments that the `pm-suspend` command works properly with your laptop, we can now tell it to use that command exclusively to suspend it.

Open a terminal and type in `gksudo gedit /etc/default/acpi-support`

Enter your admin password when prompted.

Look for the line that says `SUSPEND_METHODS="dbus-pm dbus-hal pm-utils"`

Change the line to read `SUSPEND_METHODS="pm-utils"`

Save and close the editor, and then reboot your laptop.

**Create suspend scripts:**

In terminal, type in `sudo nano /etc/acpi/events/laptop-lid-close`

Paste this into the script (right-click terminal window and click "Paste"):

```
# /etc/acpi/events/laptop-lid-close
# This is called when the user closes the laptop lid and calls
# the lidclose.sh script.

event=button/lid
action=/etc/acpi/lidclose.sh
```

To save the file in `nano`, press CTRL+O then ENTER.  (That is the letter O, not zero.)  Then press CTRL+X to exit.

Make the file executable with `sudo chmod +x  /etc/acpi/events/laptop-lid-close`

Now make the next script that will be executed by the one you just made.
In terminal, type `sudo nano /etc/acpi/lidclose.sh`

Paste this into the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script is called from /etc/acpi/events/laptop-lid-close

# Check if lid is opened or closed
grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
        /usr/sbin/pm-suspend; #if closed then suspend.
fi
```

Save and close with CTRL+O, ENTER, CTRL+X.  Make it executable with `sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/lidclose.sh`

Now restart `acpid` with `sudo service acpid restart`.

Now try closing the lid, wait a few seconds and reopen it.  If it doesn't suspend, reboot your computer and try it again.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't solve the problem. I had to make a hard reboot after a 2 hour long sleep.

Comment: Strange, because 5 minutes or 5 hours are the same.  The system is asleep doing nothing.  Were you running on batteries?

Comment: No, the laptop has no battery and always running on AC

Comment: So after you tried to resume what happened?  Did the power light change?  Did the fan come on?  Keyboard lights?  Was it basically everything turned back on except your screen?

Comment: Everything is turned on except for the screen but the keyboard doesn't respond (no lights : caps lock, num lock ...). I even hear the HDD spinning.

Comment: Ok, this is difficult because you screen doesn't come back on so we can try something else.  In System Settings, click on Power.  Make sure both options for "When lid is closed" are set to "Do Nothing".  Then open a terminal and type in `acpi_listen > ~/listens`.  Then close the lid for 5 seconds and reopen.  If your screen doesn't come back on you might have to hard reset.  Then post the contents of the `listens` file in your home folder.  It should say something like `button/lid LID close`.  Also, does your  laptop still sleep when you close the lid?

Comment: I Added the content of `listens ` in the post.

Comment: @eagerToLearn Great.  I added to my answer.  Follow the "Create suspend scripts" section.  This should work for you.

Comment: It goes to sleep and resumes correctly, but I had to change `grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state` to `grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state` in the file `/etc/acpi/lidclose.sh` because the other file didn't exist on my system.

Comment: Ah yes.  I should have posted `/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID*/state` which will work no matter what.  Some laptops are LID, some are LID0.  Mine is LID.  I'll change the answer.  You shouldn't have problems now.  I suspect that your computer still wasn't using pm-suspend before even with that first change, but it should now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was...

> All Settings > Brightness & Lock

Make sure *Dim Screen to Save Power* is **unchecked**.